# Is there synthetic tracking data available in CustusX?

Tags: plugins

I'm developing a plugin for custusX. I prefer developing on my own PC which is not connected to a tracking system.

For video, custusX uses a webcam to generate synthetic 'example data'. Is there also a tracking source with synthetic tracking data available that can be used for developing? (Preferable two different tools tools which move around all the time). If so, how can I enable it?

Currently if I try to access the tool configuration or to initialize tracking I only get `Configuration file [] is not valid, could not configure the toolmanager.` in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a debug feature available:

> Preferences->Debug->Run Debug Tool

This will create a tool and move it along a hardcoded path determined by the extent of the currently loaded volume. In order to work, this **requires** that you already have loaded a volume.

You should consider if you really need this. Alternatively, simply turn off the auto-start tracking in

> Preferences->Automation->Auto Start Tracking

The auto-start streaming can also be turned off.

If what you need is to move the slice planes, note that the mouse also is a tool which always is present. this tool can be moved by interacting with the 2D views or directly in the Tool Properties Widget.

Answer (score 1):

Another debug feature is:

> Preferences->Debug->Debug manual tool

This will give manual tool the properties of the first physical tool (need to start tracking or at least run Tracking->Tool configuration). This can be used to move a probe or a tool. Will only allow you to move one tool though. To show the tool you will have to right-click in the 3D view and select "Show Manual Tool".

The manual tool can be moved by clicking in 2D/3D views or by using the "Tool Properties" widget. To change the tool orientation you have to use the "Tool Properties" widget (press the Toggle Edit Matrix button to open the tool controllers).

Combining this with "Run Debug Tool" (described by Christian) can give you two moving tools, one following a hardcoded path, and the other one controlled with the manual tool.